# Firebase Export to BigQuery: event_timestamp changes when going from intraday to full day table

Tags: firebase, google-bigquery, google-analytics-firebase

I have a mobile application that is connected to a BigQuery Warehouse through Firebase export. For keeping my dashboards up to date, I run incremental jobs (dbt) several times a day to extract data from the tables BigQuery creates that contain imported Firebase data. (see [this article](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/7029846)).

For real-time data streaming, a table with the suffix "_intraday" is created. Once that day is over, the data is moved over to the table which only contains full days and the intraday table is deleted.

It looks like when this happens (moving from intraday to full day), the event_timestamp (UNIX) is slightly changed (a few milliseconds) for each entry. The problem: I defined a combination of user_id and event_timestamp as unique key. Due to this issue, the first job dealing with the moved table will identify each row as a new, unique row, duplicating my resulting data exactly by 2.

Has anyone ever seen this issue and knows if it's expected? Do you know any other solution than implementing an event ID on the client, giving each event a unique identifier (through custom event params) and using this instead of user_id + timestamp?

[auto-created tables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yFiQQ.png)

Thank you.

Comment: How frequent are events? Not a solution to the underlying issue but you could round to a less precise time measurement like CEIL(event_timestamp/10)?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the "event_server_timestamp_offset" should solve this.

```
event_timestamp - ifnull(event_server_timestamp_offset, 0) as event_timestamp
```

Answer (score 0):

I want to confirm that this bug (or feature?) occurs. The solution provided by ChunYu sometimes does not work also, because there are cases in which the formula provided misses the consolidated timestamp by 1, 2 microsseconds. I am not sure if the error is always small, and maybe you can derive some logic to deal with this uncertainty.

I personally think it is better to wait for the data to be consolidated in the daily tables, because this data won't be changed anymore. Or maybe you can user your hot, real-time data, but then replace it by the consolidated data.

There is also another [post](https://www.reddit.com/r/bigquery/comments/rxauzg/question_about_events_intraday_table_and/) that confirms this issue.